# Github action Eslint passed when there is an error

Tags: github, eslint, github-actions

I am trying to run Eslint as an Github Action, but I have no clue why is the following test passing even though there is a clear error.

[image]

Here's my workflow definition

```yaml
# This workflow uses actions that are not certified by GitHub.
# They are provided by a third-party and are governed by
# separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support
# documentation.
# ESLint is a tool for identifying and reporting on patterns
# found in ECMAScript/JavaScript code.
# More details at https://github.com/eslint/eslint
# and https://eslint.org

name: ESLint

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    # The branches below must be a subset of the branches above
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  eslint:
    name: Run eslint scanning
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      security-events: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install ESLint
        run: |
          npm install eslint@8.10.0
          npm install @microsoft/eslint-formatter-sarif@2.1.7

      - name: Run ESLint
        run: npx eslint .
          --config .eslintrc.json
          --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx
        continue-on-error: false
```

Answer (score -2):

When you do an eslint CI, an action will only pass if there are no lint errors, that means you have to use an a variable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).